# How to use TPCircularBuffer for Video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, video-streaming

We have a VoIP app for iOS platform. Where we are using `TPCircularBuffer` for audio buffering and it's performance is so good.

So i was wondering if it's possible to use `TPCircularBuffer` for Video buffering also. I have searched a lot but didn't find anything useful on "Using `TPCircularBuffer` for Video". Is that even possible ??  If yes, then can anyone shade some light on it ? And any code sample would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you *could* copy your video frame's pixels into a `TPCircularBuffer`, and you'd technically have a video ring buffer, but you've already lost the efficiency race at that point because you don't have time to copy that much data around. You need to keep a reference to your frames.

Or, if you *really* wanted to mash a solution into `TPCircularBuffer`, you could write the `CMSampleBuffer` pointers into the buffer (carefully respecting retain and release). But that seems heavy handed, as you're really not gaining anything from `TPCircularBuffer`'s magical memory mapping wrapping because pointers are so small.

I would simply make my own `CMSampleBufferRef` ring buffer. You can [grab a prebuilt circular buffer](https://github.com/quinntaylor/CHDataStructures/blob/master/source/CHCircularBuffer.h) or do the clock arithmetic yourself:

```
 CMSampleBufferRef  ringBuffer[10]; // or some other number

 ringBuffer[(++i) % 10] = frame;
```

Of course your real problem is not the ring buffer itself, but dealing with the fact that decompressed video is very high bandwidth, e.g. each frame is  8MB for 1080p, or 200MB to store 1 second's worth at 24fps, so you're going to have to get pretty creative if you need anything other than a microscopic video buffer.

Some suggestions:

- the above numbers are for RGBA, so try working in YUV, where the numbers become 3MB and 75MB/s
- try lower resolutions